# Swift 3 : db.execute not run with get path use Bundle.main.path

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I use path obtained from Bundle.main.path can not insert update sqlite database with db.execute function
No display error, I do not understand why, please help me
below is my code

```
var config = Configuration()
config.readonly = false
config.foreignKeysEnabled = false
enter code here
let path1:String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "sqlite",inDirectory: "Data")!
db = try DatabaseQueue(path: path1,configuration:  config)
--------------
try db.execute("update detail set favorite = \(newDetail.favorite!) where id = \(newDetail.id!)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not write into a file within the app bundle, you have to copy the sqlite file to e.g. the documents directory and use that copy to save your data.

Comment: thank you for supporting me, i'm a newbie, can you create an example for me?